# How to pass parameters to a running python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a class `A` extended from `threading.Thread`, now I want to pass the parameters into the running thread , I can get the thread I wanted by the following script:

```
find_thread = None
for thread in enumerate():
    if thread.isAlive():
        name = thread.name.split(',')[-1]
        if name == player_id:
            find_thread = thread #inject the parameter into this thread
            break
```

Where `find_thread` is an instance of `threading.Thread` and I have a queue in `find_thread`.

```
class A(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue =queue
    def run():
        if not self.queue.empty(): #when it's running,I want to pass the parameters here
            a=queue.get()
            process(a) #do something
```

Is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: Well you're already familiar with `queue` and have a `queue.get` (recommend `get_nowait()` instead). So why not just use `queue.put_nowait()` from whatever thread you want to and have `A` leverage the `queue.get()` you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems fine with your code, you just need to slighty modify it. You've already used `threading.Queue` I believe , you also used the queue's `get` method so I wonder why you weren't able to use its `put` method:

```
for thread in enumerate():
    if thread.isAlive():
        name = thread.name.split(',')[-1]
        if name == player_id:
            find_thread = thread
            find_thread.queue.put(...)  # put something here
            break
```

---

```
class A(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, queue)
        self.queue = queue
    def run():
        a = queue.get()                 # blocks when empty
        process(a)

queue = Queue()
thread1 = A(queue=queue,...)
```

I removed the check for the empty queue, `queue.get` blocks when the queue is empty making the check gratuitous here, this is because `a` is needed by your thread for processing.

Comment: i think there is a typo, in line  " threading.Thread.__init__(self, queue)", you don't need to pass the queue to the init, this will raise an error